# Uninitialized Constant Error: Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, integration-testing

```
Uninitialized constant Production::POverview (NameError)
    from /Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
    from /Users/simon_zhu/Documents/original_version_carmel/carmel/spec/factories/poverview.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
    from /Users/simon_zhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
```

I have the following code:

poverview.rb (factory)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :poverview, class: Production::POverview do
        name "test"
        status ["p", "d", "m"]
    end
end
```

p_overview_controller_spec.rb (spec)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Production::POverviewController do
  login_user
  # GET Request to pod_info
  describe 'GET pod_info' do
    before(:each) do
        @pods = Factory(:poverview)
        get 'show', :format => :json, :name => @pods.name
        get 'show', :format => :json, :status => @pods.status
    end


  it "should return the correct company when correct id is passed" do
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)

    for(pod in body[0])
        if(pod['name'].eql? @pod.name)
            @pod.status.should.include? pod['status']
        end
    end
  end

end
```

This is my first time writing an integration test for Factory Girl and I have this uninitialized constant error.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your model code. Are your models namespaced as your example suggests?

Comment: I think you mean controller. These tests are testing for controllers. The controllers are namespaced correctly (poverview_controller is inside of production namespace).

Comment: You are defining a factory based on a  model called Production::POverview in Factory girl. is that the name of a model? Is that a typo? that may be your issue

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused. It is my fault, the tests should be tests for models. not controllers.

Comment: so it seems that I don't have a model and that is why I am getting this error. I want a way to test my controller (which is returning json) without creating a model. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Technically speaking this is a controller test and not an integration test. With an integration test you do normally hit the database and test the entire application stack. If you are trying to just test the controller you and you don't want to hit the database you should research mocking and stubbing.  You basically just create fake objects with the stubbed out methods and attributes you need instead. checkout rspec mocks or similar library https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

Answer (score -1):

Also your test setup looks very odd. It definitely looks like you are confusing integration and controller test.

Here is a post to get you started. I recommend doing some more research on testing in rails.
https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-testing-antipatterns-controllers.html